# Selenium Manager not working on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

trying to run a lambda on AWS that uses selenium and chromedriver
uploaded a layer that contains selenium v4.13 and chromedriver v2.24
I understand that this version of selenium contains selenium manager which helps to find the chrome executable.
my code snippet below works on my local but on AWS lambda it does not.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome configuration
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
>     "download.default_directory": '/tmp',  # Set a temporary download directory
>     "download.prompt_for_download": False,
>     "download.directory_upgrade": True,
>     "safebrowsing.enabled": True
> })

use chrome as browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

try:
code
```

After testing the lambda,
I receive this error message.

`Response { "errorMessage": "Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location\n", "errorType": "NoSuchDriverException",`

Checked the error message website, but as my selenium is v4.13, it is not supposed to happen. any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: used https://github.com/diegoparrilla/headless-chrome-aws-lambda-layer
managed to run in python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I found manually specifying the `chromedriver` path worked:

```
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

When Selenium's driver manager isn't working, you can try using the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) driver manager:

(`pip install seleniumbase` and run with `python`)

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
driver.quit()
```

(Note that the downloads folder is `./downloaded_files/` with SeleniumBase)